# What is an effective data structure to contain multiple complex class objects and organize them by one common parameter?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, arraylist, data-structures

I am writing a program in which I will read data from multiple files into an `ArrayList<E>` based container and output the processed data onto a linechart graphing the numeric values of the data (y-axis) by the date the data was recorded (x-axis).

One of three key classes I constructed was a base class `DataPoint` which does the bulk of data processing and validation for `DataPoint` class objects.

Another is `DataArrayList<T extends DataPoint>` extended from its superclass `ArrayList<E>`. `DataArrayList` is an interface (I think I'm using that word correctly) which sorts, summarizes, and contains `DataPoint` class objects.

The last key class, and the one I have struggled with, is `HomeDataPoint` which will contain a number of `DataPoint` class objects for **one point in time**, so each `DataPoint` must be within the same specified time period of each other. I've been testing this with the specified time period being a default of one day (each contained `DataPoint` must be read on the same day), but ultimately I feel my current data structures are inadequate as I've created, destroyed, redefined, and recreated them countless times. Namely, I've tried storing the contained `DataPoint` objects in ArrayLists, LinkedHashSets, and as individual `DataPoint` objects. Between the interactions with generics, the encapsulation of the data, and parallel processing of input, I have been pretty lost.

Here is the code for the `HomeDataPoint` `insert()` method, an enum which holds the type of possible incoming `DataPoint` class objects, and the declaration of it's member variables:

```
private enum DataType
            {
                WEATHER_CLASS(WeatherDataPoint.class), 
ELECTRIC_CLASS(ElectricDataPoint.class), GAS_CLASS(GasDataPoint.class);

            private final Class<? extends DataPoint> type;

            DataType(Class<? extends DataPoint> type)
            {
                this.type = type;
            }

            public Class<? extends DataPoint> getType()
            {
                return type;
            }
        }

        private DataArrayList<WeatherDataPoint> weatherLowPoints = null;
        private DataArrayList<WeatherDataPoint> weatherHighPoints = null;
        private DataArrayList<ElectricDataPoint> electricPoints = null;
        private DataArrayList<GasDataPoint> gasPoints = null;
```

And the `insert()` method:

```
public boolean insert(DataPoint dataElement)
        {
            if (totalSize() > 0 && !getDate().substring(0, 10).equals(dataElement.getDate().substring(0, 10)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (totalSize() == 0)
            {
                setDate(dataElement.getDate());
            }

            for (DataType type : DataType.values())
            {
                if (type.getType().equals(dataElement.getClass()))
                {
                    switch (type)
                    {
                        case WEATHER_CLASS:
                            weatherLowPoints.add((WeatherDataPoint) dataElement);
                            weatherHighPoints.add((WeatherDataPoint) dataElement);
                            return true;
                        case ELECTRIC_CLASS:
                            electricPoints.add((ElectricDataPoint) dataElement);
                            return true;
                        case GAS_CLASS:
                            gasPoints.add((GasDataPoint) dataElement);
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I was kinda worried I am being to general. I don't know what I want to ask, but I know what I want to do. I think the part that needs the most improvement is the `insert()` method. As is, if a `DataPoint` object of class `WeatherDataPoint`, for example, were passed into the `insert()` method, that point would be added to both `weatherLowPoints` and `weatherHighPoints`. I would prefer to control which one I added to, (the one with high temperature points or low temperature points) but my current structure doesn't allow this easily, especially since I'd like this to work generally.

Comment: You rambled on a lot there without saying much, and then never got around to asking a question. Or, in other words, "huh?". Seriously, I have no idea what you're trying to do or what you want us to help you with. Please edit your text and at least *ask a question*.

Comment: Sorry. At this point I feel like I can't come up with a specific question because I've got issues with this code that are linked to the larger structure of each of the `DataPoint` classes. I tried deleting my post since it's rather unhelpful but I'm not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Visitor pattern for your DataPoint class so that you don't have to do type casting.

Instead of switching on type you just need to call `dataElement.accept(yourVisitor);`

You could also use polymorphism directly if you think that the processing you need to do should be part of Data Point class:
https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: Thanks! I've been reluctant to make `DataPoint` an abstract class because I instantiate it in the `DataArrayList` class, but I feel that was only because I didn't try hard enough to find a workaround having to instantiate it. The idea of a `accept(DataPoint p)` method does seem sensible though.